# Prove a power series funcion is continuous

Tags: power-series, continuity

How do i prove the function:

$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{^{n^{0.5}}}(x^{2n}-x^{2n+1})$

is continuous in [0,1]?

I tried to look at this functions as:

$g(x)=(1-x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{^{n^{0.5}}}x^{2n}$

but I couldn't find a way solving it...

Comment: Your TeX is not making sense, $\sqrt{^n}$

Comment: my mistake... now it's supposed to be fine

Comment: Did you try to calculate the radius of convergence?

Comment: Yeah it is 1...
But it just proves that the function is continuous in every closed interval [0,r] while 0<r<1, no?

Comment: It is continuous on every closed interval in $(-1,1)$. So the only thing left to proof is the continuity at $1$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the series converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.  We can show
$$
\frac{x^{(2 n)} - x^{(2 n + 1)}}{\sqrt{n}} \le \frac{\Bigl(\frac{2n}{2 n + 1}\Bigr)^{2 n}}{\sqrt{n} (2 n + 1)} \approx \frac{1}{2 e n^{3/2}}
$$
and $\sum 1/(2en^{3/2})$ converges.